# Spring Security for Spring MVC and Spring REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I and my team have developed a small spring project. We have jsp pages in which we have written ajax calls and through these calls data is fetched, as JSON, and displayed through javascript. Now we need to add security to both, the JSP pages and REST services.

Our requirements:

1. The server should be stateless
2. Client cannot be expected to store cookies.
3. Credentials sent to the server should not be plain text

I am new to Spring Security so I would appreciate if I can get any help in implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

1 . The server should be state less.
Starting spring 3.1 it is easy as setting an attribute in your spring security http tag.

> `<http create-session="stateless"> ..</http>`

2 . Client cannot be expected to store cookies.
Then I would opt for basic authentication for the rest api and ajax calls. 
The client however has to cache the username and password and send it with each request.

3 . Credentials to the server should not be plaintext.
Use HTTPS with a valid SSL Certificate.

Comment: Thanks alot. Can you please elaborate the step 2. How should I cache the username and password? And will doing so create a security hole?